# Why CAS 2.0 Framework doesn't work?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, code-access-security

I'm playing with CAS in Framework 2.0 (I know that it's obsolete).

I have following code, that I'm trying hard to crash. I've compiled project in 2.0 framework:

```
 using System;
 using System.Security;
 using System.Security.Permissions;

 namespace Authenticode
 {
    class Program
    {
         public static void DoSthmUnmanaged()
         {
             SecurityPermission perm = new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode);
             perm.Demand();
         }

         public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
              Program.DoSthmUnmanaged();

              Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
              Console.ReadKey(true);
         }
     }
  }
```

I copy `exe` file to network drive, then open 'mscorcfg.msc' and evaluate assembly from network drive - Code group is `Machine\All_Code\LocalIntranet_Zone` which is expected. When I execute it from network all works fine and I don't get it!

It's supposed to throw exception since code from LocalIntranet doesn't has permission to run unmanaged code. Why does it work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your machine has 3.5 SP 1 installed, remember that that builds on top of 2.0, and it was that Service Pack that switched exes run from network shares to running with Full Trust.

From [What's New in the .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713697%28VS.90%29.aspx):

> Managed applications that are opened from network shares have the same behavior as native applications by running with full trust.

Comment: Interesting. Then maybe `mscorcfg.msc` was not changed after 3.5 SP1 changes?

Comment: @nikita - From a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2008/05/12/fulltrust-on-the-localintranet.aspx) about the change: "The core of this change is a modification in how we assign evidence to network launched applications.  When we see an .exe launched directly off a network share, rather than giving that .exe Zone evidence of LocalInranet, we instead give the .exe Zone evidence of MyComputer." - key being "launched directly". If you load the assembly via other means (e.g. `mscorcfg`), it still gets LocalIntranet.

Comment: Then that's the answer I suppose! Thanks!